# How can I tell in client HTML page if a standard POST has failed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

This seems like a really stupid and obvious question, but I've just been through reams of search results that only address Ajax requests, not plain HTTP. Lets say I have a little login form:

```
<form action="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="1234567">
    <input class="form-control username" id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="">
    <input class="form-control password" id="Password" name="Password" type="password">
    <button type="submit" class="btn loginBtn">SIGN IN</button>
</form>
```

When the button is pressed, the data is wrapped up and sent to the web server in an HTTP POST request. I want to tell if the request fails for any of the reasons @PaulProgrammer cites below. If I was using Ajax code, this would be very easy, but I would have a large number of forms to convert such.

My hope is that I can hook into whatever code sends the requests and handles their response. My main question is something along the line of "what response code do I get when the user clicks 'SIGN IN'.

Comment: Post your `Login` method, In what scenario would your `POST` fail? As something fails in the `Login` method?

Comment: There is an exception in the login method, or the connectivity between browser and app is compromised.

Comment: using jquery you have different callbacks to tell you if the response has succeeded or failed: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.  And if it is a success, then it depends on the reponse from the page (ie the data passed back to the success function) as to whether or not you can see if the login is successful

Comment: isn't @ProfK talking about something like `<form action="api/someMagicPlace/PasswordRecover" method="POST"> ... </form>`?

Comment: @ProfK when you say connectivity, as in the user disconnects in the middle of the POST? I just want to make sure I understand everything. (Better than re-writing an answer several times).

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury If so, then you can't do it client side, you would only be able to do it seerver side

Comment: Assuming I understood, if it's request failed, the xhr error is called, and in the 2nd case, the request does succeed (auth process), so wouldn't/shouldn't the response to the xhr request return that (e.g. `4.x` response header)?

Comment: This would have to be handled server side if you aren't using ajax to send the request. there is no code to "hook into." If the client loses connection to the server, you'll have no control of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when dealing with plain html is not 'you' as the application that gets the response but the client's browser so you cannot hook into anything because there is nothing you can hook into.

when only html is involved there are 2 parts communicating: the web server and the browser.

client side you have nothing to hook into to control what is sent back from the server (and hence from the application) so there is no way to handle the result sent back from the server; it is the browser that decides how to handle the result.